# Support for Custom Validation Messages(Validation Rules) on Object in Different Languages

Tags: validation-rule, object, language

I am trying to support multi language error message support for my application. So I want to display my validation rule messages in different languages. Is there a way to do this in salesforce? [image]

I need to support the error message which we enter to have multi language support. Should I convert all these validations to the trigger(and then handle the message there) or is there a way that I can call a function to change these validation messages?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/706/validation-rule-error-message-in-other-language

Answer (score 2):

Enable translation through Setup -> Translation Workbench -> Translation Settings.
You need enable languages and people you will be responsible to translate to those language.

Then selected person can go to Setup -> Translation Workbench -> Translate.
Select language  and select your "component" as "validation error messages". All your validation error messages will be listed, select your desired message and under "Error Message Translation" double click to enable input field and put your translation in that field.